# How to call direct imports of libraries in the creation of a Python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi, python-packaging

**Background**

I'm trying to create a Python package with a semi-complicated structure. I have published a few packages before, and because they were simple, I put all the classes and functions necessary in `__init__.py` itself. For example, the file structure of one of my simple packages would be:

```
Package/
    venv # my virtual environment
    package-name/
        __init__.py
    setup.py # with setuptools, etc.
```

A sample `__init__.py` file from a sample package would be:

```py
# __init__.py from a sample simple package
import requests

class User:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.something = requests.get(url).json()['something']

    def do_something(self):
        return float(self.something) * 10
```

As a sample package like this is basic and only requires the `User` class, this would suffice. On installing the package with `pip`, using `import package-name` works to call the `User` object.

```py
# random computer with simple package installed
import package_name

api = package_name.User()
```

And this works fine.

**Question**

A more complicated package like the one I'm working on cannot contain all classes and functions directly in the `__init__.py` file. The structure is below:

```
Package/
    venv # my virtual environment
    package-name/
        __init__.py
        related.py
        something.py
    setup.py
```

The problem is that I can't quite figure out how to get the contents of `related.py` and `something.py` to work implicitly. By implicitly, I mean that when the user executes `import package_name`, they can use `package_name.attribute` to access any attributes from any of the files, whether it's in `__init__.py`, `related.py`, or `something.py`.

Currently, if I structure the `__init__.py` file like this:

```py
# complex package __init__.py
from package_name import related
from package_name import something
```

The user still has to call `related` and `something` as attributes of `package_name`:

```py
# random computer user file with package_name installed
import package_name

x = package_name.related.x()
y = package_name.something.y()
```

I want them to be able to do this instead:

```py
# random computer user file with package_name installed
import package_name

x = package_name.x()
y = package_name.y()
```

Without having to themselves write: `from package_name import related` and `from package_name import something` on their own computer.

Apologies for the long question but I wanted to be as clear as possible about what I'm asking because there are a lot of moving parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever names are available in your `__init__.py` will be available as `package_name.whatever` when someone does `import package_name`.  So if you want to make names from submodules available, you can do `from package_name.related import x` (or `from .related import x`) inside your `__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks. In this way, inside of `__init__.py`, I can say `from package_name.related import *` and `from package_name.something import *` and expect everything to work implicitly, in that a user just has to `import package_name` to access all attributes of `related` and `something` with `package_name.x()` or `package_name.y()` regardless of what (sub)module they came from.